# Why doesn't Core know where the transaction is coming from

Tags: transactions, blockchain, bitcoin-core

Someone I know sent me a transaction. I know where it came from, and blockchain.info knows it too. But why does BTC Core say it's unknown?

Can't it find the address by looking at the blockchain?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'From' field was intended for online transactions, a feature that was removed many years ago. For more information, see [IP Transactions](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/IP_transaction).

Comment: I was asking, why can't Bitcoin Core find the from address?

Comment: Because there is no 'from address'. There may be one or more inputs that have known addresses associated with them, but you shouldn't discriminate payments based on that. If you want to know who paid you, give different people different payment addresses.

Comment: See also: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12330/how-can-i-tell-what-input-address-sent-me-coin